# How is the ToString method of the Object class able to discover the type of an object?

Tags: c#, .net

How is the `ToString` method of the Object class able to discover the type of an object?

Comment: "discover" how? (These little explanations make the questions so much more useful.)

Comment: @Amio, what exactly do you need ? how ToString method works for different types ?

Answer (score 4):

Default implementation of `Object.ToString` is using [Object.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method, whose' implementation is dependent on CLR.

Comment: Thanks Euphoric thats i want to know

Comment: @Amio, your comments have cleared up the things :) +1 Euphoric

Answer (score 2):

```
Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().FullName);
```

From Microsoft's Source Code:

```
// Returns a String which represents the object instance.  The default 
// for an object is to return the fully qualified name of the class. 
//
public virtual String ToString() 
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

`GetType().ToString()` basically returns the 'Name' of the type, which is the "full name" or fully qualified name, such as `System.Object`. Note that the name includes the namespaces.

Comment: Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().FullName); does not print anything

Comment: @Amio; It has to result in some string.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToString()` Methode of an Object is actually to set how an object is beeing represented as a string, so if its implemented in any class an instance of this class will be showed as its set in this methode.

Take a looka t this example from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx):

```
using System;

public class Object2
{
   private object value;

   public Object2(object value)
   {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return base.ToString() + ": " + value.ToString();
   }
}

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Object2 obj2 = new Object2('a');
      Console.WriteLine(obj2.ToString());
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       Object2: a
```

If the Methode is implemented in a subclass it will be called in this class and run the classes spicific implementation of ToString(), determining the classtype in which its called can be done for example either by [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) or [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Classes provides their own implementation of `ToString()` by **overriding** the base class method. Thats how you see particular implementation of the method.

You may see: [How to: Override the ToString Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Example from the above link:

```
class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
        }
    }
```

To use it:

```
Person person = new Person { Name = "John", Age = 12 };
Console.WriteLine(person);
// Output:
// Person: John 12
```

In the above example you have a class `Person` which is overriding `ToString` method of the base class `object`. Now when you call the `person.ToString()` it calls the implementation of your `ToString` method, since you have override the existing implementation.

Comment: -1 I believe he is asking about default implementation. Not how to override it.

Comment: @Euphoric, I believe he is asking about how ToString method determines the type to call the method on.

Comment: @Euphoric, may be I read the question incorrectly, but I believe its the overriding of the ToString that needs to be understood

Comment: Answer the question, not what you "believe" the answer should be.

Comment: @AMissico - the question *is* poorly worded. I thought the OP was asking about overrides as well. It was only when I saw an answer referencing the default behaviour of `ToString` printing the object's type that I saw a different way to read the question.

Comment: @AMissico, you statement is amazing. I think I should answer what I believe should be the answer

Comment: Hey Habib in mean time i checks the answer by programming .And other thing i m student and fresher to this so excuse me if any wrong with u.As u say i will improves....thanks

Comment: @Habib, of course answer what you believe is the answer. Not what the answer should be. Two different things.